# Does a shredded book contain more or less information (or the same) than the original book

Tags: entropy, information

If I shred a book into numerous pieces, and scatter them, so that the original text is completely unreadable, then for me, as a reader, the book has lost all its information. Its entropy has greatly increased. As a reader, the book's information rested upon a state of minimal entropy. However, my (limited) understanding of Shannon's information theory is that the 'information' in the shredded book has increased along with its entropy. Is there a way of reconciling the conventional/layperson's understanding of information as an ordered presentation of knowledge (like a well-written book) with the Shannon equation of information with entropy/disorder? Apologies if I have failed to grasp something fundamental.

Comment: By this logic, when you unplug a USB drive it loses all of its information

Comment: "*However, my (limited) understanding of Shannon's information theory is that the 'information' in the shredded book has increased along with its entropy.*" Does it not refer to the amount of new information that can be gained by examining the particular arrangement of shredded pieces? In contrast, one obtains no new information from carefully examining the intact book, relative to one's existing knowledge about the correctly arranged text.

Comment: Shannon's entropy is the entropy of the text, regardless of its support (a book, a speech, a digital file). If there is no more text, there is no associated entropy either. If the text can be reconstituted, then it's entropy has not changed (it's the same text). The entropy that has increased when the book was destroyed is not Shannon's, it is the entropy of the physical system that is the book itself, as a material object.